# MySQL View table Query Showing last 3 digits

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a view table which will show a `Name` & `QueueCode`. But the `QueueCode` are from ID and only shows the last 3 digits.

Here is my code :

```
CREATE VIEW View4
AS SELECT nama "PatientName", ID "QueueCode"
FROM dokter
WHERE ID= (SELECT RIGHT(ID,3) From dokter);
```

When I use `Select*from view4`, it says:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Can any of you help me?

Comment: I think you need `IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW View4
AS SELECT nama "PatientName", RIGHT(ID,3) "QueueCode"
FROM dokter;
```

Comment: wow spot on! thanks a bunch! earlier I said "i have 2 questions, now for the second question "from that 3 digits" how do I show only even number? i.e 002, 004, 006?

Comment: do i use this query? `WHERE MOD (id,2)=0` ?

Comment: If you want your view show only even numbers then yes. If you want to filter view's results then its `WHERE MOD(QueueCode,2)=0`.